# Video upload Issues in Youtube using youtube IOS API only New google account

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, gtm-oauth2

**Issues Scenario :** I'm tried upload the video to youtube using iOS Youtube API in new Google account. After logged success i'm getting the below exception. Can you please advice how to fix in objective c.How to fix it please advice me

```
unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)'
```

I removed debugging in Code i'm getting

```
An error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=-32602 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Unauthorized)" UserInfo=0x17547f680 {error=Unauthorized, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Unauthorized), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x1744557b0: {message:"Unauthorized" data:[1] code:-32602}}
```

**Working Scenario :**  I tried to upload with old google account(this account already  logged and created chennal manually) video uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error was very simple. Your google account did not have a YouTube channel associated with it.

Comment: Can you please advice how to associate with YouTube chennal for new account.?

Comment: login via your google account, go to youtube channel,create a channel then try using that creadential

Comment: But using youtube API how to create channel programmatically in objective c ?

Comment: sorry i think they dont provide it check https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: please check good tutorial over here
http://www.ongraph.com/blog/youtube-api-for-ios-uploading-a-video

Comment: Thanks for your advice and links. I will check and update you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80360/discussion-between-2vision2-and-iphonemaclover).